# How i can use method such as swipe or zoom etc from WebDriver

Tags: java, methods, appium

How i can use method such as swipe or zoom etc from WebDriver

swipe and zoom are method are available into appium driver and i am using WebDriver ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use such methods from WebDriver.

You need to use accordingly AppiumDriver, AndroidDriver, IOSDriver.
E.g. `this.iosDriver = new IOSDriver(remoteAddress, capabilities)`